# How to add UITableViewController as subview of the main view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, subview

I want to separate my code out and make my UITableView into a new controller + .xib file.

My problem is that when I add the subview, it is overtop of the main view and therefore blocks the buttons on the UINavigationBar of the main view.
[image]

So i want the tableView to be added as a subView of the MainViewController, but to be 'cropped' so the top of the window is showing the MainViewController's navbar. At the moment it is showing because I've set the topview to transparent, but it cannot detect events because the second view is overtop of it.

Comment: Are you using a `UINavigationController` as the parent view?  If so, why aren't you just setting the `rootViewController` property of that to your new table view controller?  If you aren't using a `UINavigationController` as the parent vc, why not?

Comment: After changing my MainViewController to a UINavigationController I now cannot see the buttons in the MainViewController's xib.

I'm not looking for any navigation yet. I just want a tableView showing ontop of the MainViewController's view, but not at 100% height. I only want it to be in the middle of the view

Comment: Upon reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) I'm going to refactor my code to have a ``UINavigationController`` as the root, and then add the top bar and tableView as seperate subviews